# Tomcat ClientAbortException Listener?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, tomcat

Our Tomcat 6 Server is reporting quite a few ClientAbortException errors, which I believe is down to say a user navigating away from the page before its fully loaded. We are also getting No buffer space available (maximum connections reached? errors.

Is there a way of creating a ClientAbortException Listener to terminate any Abandoned Connection Clean Up or unused http threads and delete any byte data used for incomplete downloaded images.

This project is inherited and I've noticed that even when running locally if I start VisualJVM and view the monitor and then open a website locally I see an Abandoned Connection Clean Up thread created and a number of http threads created. If I open another website on the same local web server I can see yet again another Abandoned Connection Clean Up thread created and another set of http threads created. If I navigate through the pages, I don't see any other connections created, mainly because the project is using database pooling but if I close the browser the threads are still running, they are not being freed up.

Needless to say, as soon as the server has been running for a number of days or is under load the aforementioned errors are generated.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: ClientAbortExceptions don't result in leaked connections. If they did, everybody would have this problem. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: That's a comfort in some way, but am at a loss as how to resolve the following errors:

INFO: Maximum number of threads (200) created for connector with address and No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?

I have the server.xml configured as:

<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="400" minSpareThreads="4"/>

How can I get Maximum number of threads (200) created for connector with address if its set to 400?